# 2d laplace equation seperation by variables with confusing boundaries

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Solve Laplace's equation (using separation of variables) $U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$ for $U(x,y)$ on square $0 \leq x \leq L$,  $0 \leq y \leq L$
subject to following boundary conditions:

$$U(x,L)=0$$
$$U_x(0,y)=0$$
$$U_x(L,y)=\cos(\frac{\pi y}{2L})$$
$$U_y=(x,0)=1-\cos(\frac{\pi x}{L})$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve this problem, so let's look at two problems I do know how to solve. The first will be $\nabla^2U=0$, $U_x(0,y)=U_x(L,y)=U(x,L)=0$, and $U_y(x,0)=1-\cos\frac{\pi x}L$. We can solve by separation of variables with $U(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, so $YX^{\prime\prime}+XY^{\prime\prime}=0$ and
$$\frac1XX^{\prime\prime}=-\frac1YY^{\prime\prime}=-\lambda$$
Where $\lambda$ is the separation constant. If $\lambda<0$, then $X=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}x+c_2\sinh\sqrt{-\lambda}x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}$, so $c_2=0$ and at $x=L$, $X^{\prime}(L)=c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}\sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}L)=0$, so also $c_1=0$, the trivial solution.

If $\lambda=0$, then $X=c_1+c_2x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2$, so $X_0(x)=1$ is a solution that also satisfies $X^{\prime}(L)=0$. Then $Y^{\prime\prime}=0$ so $Y(y)=c_3+c_4(L-y)$, and $Y(L)=0=c_3$ so $Y_0(y)=L-y$

If $\lambda>0$, then $X=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}x+c_2\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=c_2\sqrt{\lambda}=0$, so $c_2=0$, and at $x=L$, $X^{\prime}(L)=-c_1\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}L=0=\sin n\pi$, so $\lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}$ and $X_n(x)=\cos\frac{n\pi x}L$. Then $Y^{\prime\prime}(y)=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}Y$ with solution $Y=c_3\cosh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L+c_4\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_3$ so $Y_n(y)=\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$. Then we have
$$U(x,y)=a_0(L-y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$$
And
$$U_y(x,0)=1-\cos\frac{\pi x}L=-a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{n\pi}La_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\cosh n\pi$$
We could use orthogonality of the eigenfunctions to determine the coefficients $a_n$, but by inspection $a_0=-1$, $a_1=\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}$ and all other $a_n=0$, so
$$U_1(x,y)=y-L+\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$$
The other problem I know how to solve is $\nabla^2U=0$, $U_x(0,y)=U(x,L)=U_y(x,0)=0$, and $U_x(L,y)=\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}$. Again $U(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, so $YX^{\prime\prime}+XY^{\prime\prime}=0$ and
$$\frac1XX^{\prime\prime}=-\frac1YY^{\prime\prime}=\lambda$$
If $\lambda<0$, then $Y=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}y+c_2\sinh\sqrt{-\lambda}y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}$ so $c_2=0$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}L$, so we only get the trivial solution.

If $\lambda=0$, then $Y=c_1+c_2y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2$ and at $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1$, i.e. only the trivial solution.

If $\lambda>0$, then $Y=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}y+c_2\sin\sqrt{\lambda}y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=\sqrt{\lambda}c_2$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}L=\cos\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$, so $\lambda_n=\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)^2\pi^2}{L^2}$ and $Y_n=\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L$. Then $X^{\prime\prime}=\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi^2}{L^2}X$ with solution $X=c_3\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L+c_4\sinh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_4\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}L$, so $c_4=0$, and $X_n(x)=\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$. So this time
$$U(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$$
And
$$U_x(L,y)=\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}Lb_n\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L\sinh\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$$
As before we find by inspection that $b_0=\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}$ and all other $b_n=0$, so the solution to this problem is
$$U_2(x,y)=\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}\cosh\frac{\pi x}{2L}$$
We can find the solution to the original problem by superposition
$$\begin{align}U(x,y)&=U_1(x,y)+U_2(x,y)\\
&=y-L+\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L+\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}\cosh\frac{\pi x}{2L}\end{align}$$